# Google app engine php connect to external microsoft sql server database

Tags: php, sql-server, google-app-engine, pdo

I've been searching and can't find an answer.

Is it possible, using PHP in the Google App Engine (GAE), to connect to a remote MS SQL Server database?

I tried a connection with PDO with different names of common drivers but it always gives me the same error:

> "could not find driver"

The code I use to create the connection (works outside appengine) is:

```
new PDO(
  "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database",
  $uid,
  $pwd,
  array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  )
);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of AppEngine are you using? Standard, Flex?

Comment: Standard with php 7.2

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [that is for App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/using-third-party-databases) you can connect an external databases if your database server and your firewall are configured properly to accept connections. For the connection,  you could use remote sockets from PHP,  so check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/sockets/) about it. Only keep in mind that sockets [are only available for paid apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas?hl=en#Sockets).